# Unable to uninstall a package showing via apt list

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, uninstall, dkms

I am running Ubuntu 20.04LTS. When I search for virtualbox in my packages, it shows a number of packages.

```
~$ apt list | grep virtualbox

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

boinc-virtualbox/focal 7.16.6+dfsg-1 amd64
unity-scope-virtualbox/focal,focal 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu2 all
virtualbox-dkms/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox-ext-pack/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-dkms/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-source-hwe/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-source/focal-updates,focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox-guest-utils/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox-guest-x11/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox-qt/focal-updates,now 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
virtualbox-source/focal-updates 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64
virtualbox/focal-updates,now 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
```

However, when I try to remove either of them, it says that that package is not installed, so not removed.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

--- 
~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-source

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox-source' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

---
~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-guest*

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-dkms' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-source' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-source-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Package 'virtualbox-guest-modules-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-source-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could someone help me understand what's going on here? I am fairly new to Linux. Loving it but still get confused by such things. Thanks!

Update: I get different results when using `dpkg` and `apt list` as shown below:

```
~$ dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox
rc  virtualbox                                 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1         amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
rc  virtualbox-qt                              6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1         amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface

~$ apt list --installed | grep virtualbox
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt list | grep virtualbox` lists the available packages in your software sources that **can be installed** with apt. You need to run the following command to list the packages that are currently installed with apt:

```
apt list --installed | grep virtualbox
```

Please note that this command will return an error message if you try to run it with apt-get instead of apt.

This command will return a shorter list of packages because the results of `sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-source virtualbox-guest*` show that many of the packages that are listed in the results are not currently installed.

The results of `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox` show that these two packages are manually installed: *virtualbox* and *virtualbox-qt*. You can uninstall these two packages with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox virtualbox-qt
```

The packages are selected to be purged (i.e. we want to remove everything from system directories, even configuration files). This would be a good command to run if you are planning to install a more recent version of VirtualBox.

Comment: Maybe `apt list --installed | grep virtualbox` would be simpler? And add link to [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html) for learning curve.

Comment: I usually use `dpkg` to achieve this e.g. `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox`, just another way of doing things. Cheers!

Comment: @haralambov That has the same problem as the original pipeline, though. It lists all available packages, not only the ones that are installed. For this, you could add a second `grep` that checks for the `ii` that indicates the package is installed: `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox | grep ^ii`

Comment: @haralambov I updated my original post with the results for `dpkg`. I seem to be getting different results as compared to `apt list --installed`.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Using `apt list | grep virtualbox` and `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox` gives different results (as updated in my original post).

Comment: @karel "The results of `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox` show that these two packages are manually installed: _virtualbox_ and _virtualbox-qt_."   
Why do _virtualbox_ and _virtualbox-qt_ not show up when using `apt list --installed | grep virtualbox`?

Comment: @LearnerYoda `apt` works on a different layer than `dpkg` does. I've explained the basics [in a different answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350910/will-changing-the-repository-in-the-software-center-affect-sources-list/351058#351058). So if you downloaded a `*.deb` file and (manually) installed it with `dpkg -i`, it will be listed by `dpkg --list`. But it won't be listed by `apt list`, because it didn't come from a repository `apt` knows about.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Thanks for answering that comment for me.

Comment: Thank you @HenningKockerbeck. I am currently going through your previous answer. Something I am wondering about meanwhile though, I never installed virtual box manually using `.deb` package; I only ever used the `apt install` command. So I am wondering how these packages showed up in `dpkg --list | grep -i virtualbox`.  @karel, thanks for updating your answer. I think you meant `dpkg --purge` though, instead of `dpkg purge`. I was able to remove the said packages using this. If this is correct, could you please update your response. Thanks, marking your answer as accepted.